# couchdb 1.6.1 on AWS gives os_process_error 127

Tags: amazon-web-services, couchdb, spidermonkey

I am stuck on this couchdb 1.6.1 installation. The couchdb server runs fine for normal document but it gives os_process_error 127 when I execute views. I have checked the Spidermonkey installation as well, checked the libmozjs185.so.1.0 path, configured the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Below is the ldd output for couchjs. Apparently, the service does not crash, the normal documents are still accessible.

I have also modified the os_process_timeout to 60000

I installed it again on a VM on my system, and it works perfectly fine on it. But on AWS, it gives this error continuously.

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/couchdb/bin/couchjs
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff46748000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f5f70531000)
    libmozjs185.so.1.0 => /usr/local/lib/libmozjs185.so.1.0 (0x00007f5f6ffd2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5f6fcd0000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f5f6fa99000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5f6f6d7000)
    libidn.so.11 => /lib64/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f5f6f4a5000)
    libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007f5f6f27d000)
    libssl3.so => /usr/lib64/libssl3.so (0x00007f5f6f03e000)
    libsmime3.so => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007f5f6ee17000)
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007f5f6eaf9000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f5f6e8cd000)
    libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007f5f6e6c9000)
    libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007f5f6e4c4000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007f5f6e286000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5f6e06a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5f6de66000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f5f6dc22000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f5f6d93d000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f5f6d712000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f5f6d50e000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f5f6d2ff000)
    libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f5f6d0b3000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5f6ce9c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5f6cb98000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5f6c982000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f5f6c706000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5f707ae000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f5f6c499000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f5f6c0b4000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5f6beab000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f5f6bca0000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f5f6ba9c000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f5f6b882000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f5f6b666000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f5f6b445000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue on **CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)** and **CentOS release 6.7 (Final)**. I had issues like:

- /opt/apache/couchdb-1.6.1/bin/couchjs_dev: error while loading shared libraries: libmozjs185.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
- os_process_error {exit_status,127}
- libmozjs185.so.1.0 => not found

and result for command **[root@josephstar bin]# ldd /usr/local/lib/couchdb/bin/couchjs** was :

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd1039f000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x000000311e400000)
    libmozjs185.so.1.0 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003119800000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x0000003124800000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003118c00000)
    libidn.so.11 => /lib64/libidn.so.11 (0x000000312b000000)
    libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x000000312bc00000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003119400000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x0000003128400000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0000003127800000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0000003126800000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000003124c00000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003119c00000)
    libssl3.so => /usr/lib64/libssl3.so (0x0000003129000000)
    libsmime3.so => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so (0x0000003129400000)
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x0000003127c00000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x0000003125800000)
    libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x0000003125c00000)
    libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x0000003125000000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x0000003125400000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003119000000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003118800000)
    libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x000000311b000000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x0000003124400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003118400000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x000000312b400000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x000000311ac00000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x000000312b800000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x0000003127400000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x0000003126000000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x0000003129800000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x0000003127000000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x000000311a400000)
```

- I installed SpiderMonkey from http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/js185-1.0.0.tar.gz
- Then, I configured couchdb 1.6.1 by **./configure --with-erlang=/usr/lib64/erlang/usr/include --with-js-lib=/usr/local/lib/ --with-js-include=/usr/local/include/js/**
- I solved **libmozjs185.so.1.0 => not found** issue by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib`

***Finally***, CouchDB Installation is successful but when calling any view, it gives again error  **os_process_error {exit_status,127}**

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure this issue but could not find anything on this. The only thing I could understand is that there is some problem with spidermonkey. Not exactly sure what. Tried all the solutions available online but with no results. So I moved to ubuntu at last. The ubuntu apt-get has spider monkey installation and you can install it using apt-get itself and it works like a charm.

For couch 1.6.1, you can follow the same steps as written on couchdb website and can run 1.6.1 couch on ubuntu. I am using this since last 1 year without running into any problems. Please note last time when I installed it, couchdb 1.6.1 was not available in ubuntu repositories, so I had to compile it using the manual method and then installed it.

All the best.